# MongoDB - Unable to get an object's key's value in Mongo Shell

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

The following script is run in the `Mongo Shell`

```
db.patches.insert({ _id: 0, name:"n/a",os:"n/a",active:"n/a",created_at:"n/a", modified_at:"n/a"})

var a = db.patches.find().sort({_id:-1}).limit(1)

a

print(a["name"])
```

Why `unknown type` was shown instead of `"n/a"` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you mean to do `var a = db.server.find().sort({_id:-1}).limit(1)`? (`server` and not `patches`)

Anyway, [find returns a cursor](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/iterate-a-cursor/). The way cursors work is that when you call it, it prints the current document to which it points to and moves to the next, so you need to iterate it, calling `cursor.next()`.

When you're doing

`var a = db.patches.find().sort({_id:-1}).limit(1)
a`

You're printing the cursor and now `a.hasNext()` is equal to `false`.

What you want to do is:

`var a = db.patches.find().sort({_id:-1}).limit(1)
print(a.next().name)`

Or

`var a = db.patches.find().sort({_id:-1}).limit(1)
print(a.next()['name'])`.

Any of the above will print `n/a`.